# Path for American to become professor in Europe

Tags: career-path, computer-science, europe

I'm an American, and I’m considering – sometime in the future – getting a PhD in computer science. My impression is that Europe is a lovely place, both in general and because of its sane work culture. If I decide I would like to become a professor in Europe, what steps should I take?

For example:

1. Does one need to get a PhD from Europe, rather than from the U.S., to be a professor there?
2. If not, does a PhD from the UK qualify one to be a professor in continental Europe?
3. Are classes in continental Europe generally taught in English?
4. If not, does one need to be a native speaker to teach them?

Comment: Too many questions, you need to edit your post. But generally: 1) No. 2)Yes. 3) Some, especially in western Europe. 4) No.

Comment: Please also remember that Europe is not one homogeneous mass and practices vary, often significantly, between individual countries.

Comment: I don't know how much saner Europe is than the US when you restrict your sample to academics. The few academics I know in Germany work insane hours and go through their emails every single day - including weekends and holidays.

Comment: @StephanKolassa The more similar the job requirements and competitiveness to the US situation, the more similar the working culture. There are European countries with a "sane work culture" in academia, sometimes "too sane". Of course, it's probably close to impossible for someone from the US to get such a tenure position without speaking the local language.